# Rails5.0.2 enum handling invalid values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, enums, rails-activerecord

I have a Work model that includes a status enum type

```
enum status: { beginning: 0, middle: 1, end: 2 }
```

Upon creating a new Work record, there could be a scenario where the status value being passed is something like `finished`. In that case, I am getting

```
`ArgumentError: 'finished' is not a valid status`
```

Is there a way to map an invalid value to nil? This is different from `default: nil` because that only is applicable when no status is given as a value in the first place.

Would I have to rescue on ArgumentError? What is the correct way of handling this? Please provide an example!

Also, if it makes a difference my migration file is as follows:

```
 def change
    add_column :db_name, :status, :integer, default: nil
 end
```

Comment: Don't you think it's a bad practice to allow things like that implicitly pass? Why can't you change your code to stop passing wrong status names?

Comment: I'm with @nattfodd here. You could override `def status=(x)` in the model but I think you'd be better off doing this one level up.